# Preventing one site from redirecting to www. prefix in multisite

Tags: 9, redirection, multi-sites

I am using Drupal 9, multi-site. Generally, for all sites except one, i want to redirect from non-www to www prefix and i'm using the root `.htacces` file for it by uncommenting redirect rules. But the one site is 3rd level domain such as `noha.ruka.cz` and i dont want this particular site to redirect to the `www` prefix. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regular expression features of mod_rewrite—specifically `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`—to match or exclude that domain. The [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html) has a close example.